# Oracle conditional select

Tags: sql, oracle

Im sure this is an easy one.

How would I do a conditional value select on a column.

```
Basically if column1 ='Y' then display as "FOO" else if 'n' display "foobar"

select column1 from table1;
```

Comment: This isn't PL/SQL, it's plain SQL, though Oracle-flavoured. You can use `case` in PL/SQL too, but as part of a select that isn't really relevant.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

With a [simple `case` expression](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e26088/expressions004.htm):

```
select case column1 when 'Y' then 'FOO' else 'foorbar' end
from table1;
```

That assume a simple if/else. Your question specifies two values, and you can check both:

```
select case column1 when 'Y' then 'FOO' when 'n' then 'foorbar' end
from table1;
```

If you have any `column1` values other than `Y` and `n` you'd get `null`; you can still specify a different value with an `else` even if you're testing for more than one explicit value:

```
select case column1 when 'Y' then 'FOO' when 'n' then 'foorbar' else 'bar' end
from table1;
```

Answer (score 3):

An alternative syntax in Oracle is decode, I like this because it's nice and concise, but basically does the same as the case statement suggested above:

```
select decode(column1,'Y','FOO','foobar') from table1;
```

The syntax is as follows: decode( expression , search , result [, search , result]... [, default] ).

Further examples are in Oracles docs: http://www.techonthenet.com/oracle/functions/decode.php